# How to get list of Google+ Pages

Tags: google-plus

I am developing an application which will get Google Plus pages of an authenticated user. I know this has been done by HootSuite but I don't find any help on Google or here.

I'd like a way of getting all google+ pages owned or administered by a user preferably via a /me endpoint. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is only possible through the Google+ Pages API: https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup